# How to detect current media type in CLI under Windows? (DVD-RW, BD-R, etc)

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, wmi, optical-media

How to detect current media type in CLI under Windows? (DVD-RW, BD-R, etc)

I've tried with wmic cdrom get /format:list but no info about the current media type.

I want to detect if the disc is a CD, DVD, BD, RW, DL... etc. In Windows GUI under Computer we can see the information according to the icon displayed for the optical drive.

Also, I can't find the meaning of the Availability and the Capabilities values, if you know a document talking about it, it would be great.

```
C:\>wmic cdrom get /format:lis

Availability=3
Capabilities={3,4,7}
CapabilityDescriptions={"Random Access"," Supports writing"," Supports Removable
 Media"}
Caption=HL-DT-ST BD-RE  BH12LS35
CompressionMethod=Unknown
ConfigManagerErrorCode=0
ConfigManagerUserConfig=FALSE
CreationClassName=Win32_CDROMDrive
DefaultBlockSize=
Description=CD-ROM Drive
DeviceID=SCSI\CDROM&amp;VEN_HL-DT-ST&amp;PROD_BD-RE__BH12LS35\4&amp;15828421&amp
;0&amp;050000
Drive=G:
DriveIntegrity=TRUE
ErrorCleared=
ErrorDescription=
ErrorMethodology=
FileSystemFlags=
FileSystemFlagsEx=21757959
Id=G:
InstallDate=
LastErrorCode=
Manufacturer=(Standard CD-ROM drives)
MaxBlockSize=
MaximumComponentLength=254
MaxMediaSize=
MediaLoaded=TRUE
MediaType=DVD Writer
MfrAssignedRevisionLevel=1.00
MinBlockSize=
Name=HL-DT-ST BD-RE  BH12LS35
NeedsCleaning=
NumberOfMediaSupported=
PNPDeviceID=SCSI\CDROM&amp;VEN_HL-DT-ST&amp;PROD_BD-RE__BH12LS35\4&amp;15828421&
amp;0&amp;050000
PowerManagementCapabilities=
PowerManagementSupported=
RevisionLevel=
SCSIBus=5
SCSILogicalUnit=0
SCSIPort=0
SCSITargetId=0
SerialNumber=
Size=39621033984
Status=OK
StatusInfo=
SystemCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName=PC
TransferRate=4363,63636363636
VolumeName=XMEN_D1
VolumeSerialNumber=8AF2C6DC
```

**EDIT**

Running `Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMedia | Select *` give me the following result for the optical drive (a DVD is in the drive):

```
PSComputerName       : PC-JAY
__GENUS              : 2
__CLASS              : Win32_PhysicalMedia
__SUPERCLASS         : CIM_PhysicalMedia
__DYNASTY            : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH            : Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag="\\\\.\\CDROM0"
__PROPERTY_COUNT     : 23
__DERIVATION         : {CIM_PhysicalMedia, CIM_PhysicalComponent, CIM_PhysicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER             : PC-JAY
__NAMESPACE          : root\cimv2
__PATH               : \\PC-JAY\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag="\\\\.\\CDROM0"
Capacity             :
Caption              :
CleanerMedia         :
CreationClassName    :
Description          :
HotSwappable         :
InstallDate          :
Manufacturer         :
MediaDescription     :
MediaType            :
Model                :
Name                 :
OtherIdentifyingInfo :
PartNumber           :
PoweredOn            :
Removable            :
Replaceable          :
SerialNumber         :
SKU                  :
Status               :
Tag                  : \\.\CDROM0
Version              :
WriteProtectOn       :
Scope                : System.Management.ManagementScope
Path                 : \\PC-JAY\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag="\\\\.\\CDROM0"
Options              : System.Management.ObjectGetOptions
ClassPath            : \\PC-JAY\root\cimv2:Win32_PhysicalMedia
Properties           : {Capacity, Caption, CleanerMedia, CreationClassName...}
SystemProperties     : {__GENUS, __CLASS, __SUPERCLASS, __DYNASTY...}
Qualifiers           : {dynamic, Locale, provider, UUID}
Site                 :
Container            :
```

Answer (score 5):

> I want to detect if the disc is a CD, DVD, BD, RW, DL... etc. In
>   Windows GUI under Computer we can see the information according to the
>   icon displayed for the optical drive.

You have the right command, the information you seek is under the "Caption" field.

So for:

```
wmic cdrom get /format:list
```

In your example, in the Caption field you can see it is a BD-RE (blu-ray Recordable

> Caption=HL-DT-ST BD-RE  BH12LS35

For your second question:

> Also, I can't find the meaning of the Availability and the
>   Capabilities values, if you know a document talking about it, it would
>   be great.

The descriptions and everything related to this class are found on MSDN here:

[Win32_CDROMDrive class (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: forget a t in your wmic command. I'd edit but it requires me changing 6 characters :P

Answer (score 2):

The Availability is what the media is capable of, and Capability is what your drive is capable of. So:

`Availability=3

Capabilities={3,4,7}

CapabilityDescriptions={"Random Access"," Supports writing"," Supports Removable
 Media"}`

This would mean that your current media supports reading only, but not writing. The "supports removable media" probably doesn't mean anything useful. Based on the `Size=39621033984` parameter you have a standard DVD-R loaded. DL would be double that, and Blu-Ray more. Try experimenting with different media to see what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following code?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_cdromdrive -Filter "MediaLoaded=True" | Select Drive, MediaType
```